# sharding in mongodb with other type of _id

Tags: mongodb, sharding

It's possible that i face with problems in mongoDB sharding if change type of _id in mongoDB to other format same as int, string or .... ?
because the structure of _id is:
1- The first 4 bytes representing the seconds since the unix epoch
2- **The next 3 bytes are the machine identifier**
3- The next 2 bytes consists of process id
4- The last 3 bytes are a random counter value

and i think those **3 bytes that use for machine identifier** are very helpful for sharding.

Comment: the shard key needs cardinality that means many values.  how many different machine identifiers are there?

Answer (score 0):

The makeup of the ObjectId has changed.
and it has 5 bytes instead of machine id and process id.

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-bson-data-types--objectid

Answer (score 0):

No, you won't. The sharding key is either an indexed field or indexed compound fields according to Mongodb's official document.

[sharding key](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/)